# What are packaged app in context of chrome app development?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-app

I am new to chrome app development and I am trying to build a simple Chrome App which will have a database. I will be storing the data locally on the system.

While going through the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/offline_apps) in the *Saving data locally* section, there's a note which is as follows:

> Note: Packaged apps cannot use Web SQL Database or localStorage. The WebSQL specification has been deprecated for awhile now, and localStorage handles data synchronously (which means it can be slow). The Storage API handles data asynchronously.

So I am confused here, what is exactly a packaged app? And what is the other type of app where there are no restrictions on storing data?

Comment: Above that quote are three options for saving data in a Chrome app. Did you see them?

Comment: Yes, I saw them, but wanted to know which is the scenario where its not applicable, and they say its not applicable to packaged apps. So very confused. I want to completely understand that by developing in a certain way i will never be restricted with size. I am changing my focus from developing desktop apps with database to chrome apps with database. I would be very thankful if my doubt gets cleared.

Comment: With the `unlimitedStorage` permission, you can use `IndexedDB` and the virtual FileSystem API without restrictions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So I am confused here, what is exactly a packaged app?

Everything that the current documentation refers to as Chrome App. "Packaged app" is an old term for the same.

> What is the other type of app where there are no restrictions on storing data.

For completeness' sake, the other two types of apps are:

1. [Legacy packaged apps](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/apps). They are an ancient version of Chrome apps with a different API, that has been [deprecated since 2014](http://blog.chromium.org/2014/06/migrate-your-legacy-packaged-apps-to.html).
2. [Hosted apps](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/hosted_apps), which a fancy name for a webapp with a manifest file that's uploaded to the Web Store. They act pretty much like a web shortcut in the apps list (with few extra features).

Those are either not supported or completely different - they won't help you with restrictions. So, learn to use the tools that are available and are mentioned in the docs.

Comment: So in simple words what i have understood is :                                                            1. Packaged App and Chrome App are the same with just two different names.  2. Web SQL api are interfaces which allows browser applications to interact with a database installed/running on client machine, eg mysql,mongodb etc. 3. But a chrome app cannot use a web sql as per the note , so a chrome app cannot use any database installed/running on the client machine. A chrome app therefore can only use indexed DB, file system api for storage.  Correct me here if i am wrong.

Comment: 1. Correct. 2. Wrong - they are self-contained SQLite instances. 3. Correct, as per https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_deprecated

Comment: Sorry for trouble, i am going too deep, but i got interested further to know below  1. so when a browser is installed on machine, it comes with self contained sql instances. 2. Also when a browser is installed indexed db comes in built with the browser which we can use as per our need,  am i correct?

Comment: Don't quote _me_ on that, but if I remember correctly both are backed by SQLite. It's just that they are different standards and one of them won over the other.

Comment: Thank you so much Xan, you really helped me a lot and my doubt is clear now. Thank you very much :)